# "This needs reviewed." vs "This needs to be reviewed."?

Tags: american-english

As in the title:
"This needs reviewed." vs "This needs to be reviewed."

Are either of these grammatically incorrect ? And/or is one preferable to the other ? I'm not quite sure what area this falls under, so I'm having a hard time finding the correct references elsewhere. Sources preferred if possible please.

Thank you

Comment: @Laurel Wow. Yea - it does and more. I also grew up in the same region as the poster (Central-ish PA) and so maybe that explains some of my habits/confusion. Thank you ! Marking as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

"This needs reviewed" is incorrect. You would have to make it present tense. Therefore, "This needs to be reviewed" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This needs reviewed is incorrect and this needs to be reviewed is correct. What you could do to make the first one correct is drop the ending: this needs review. This practically means the same thing as the second statement, except the second phrase sounds more formal.

Answer (score 0):

"This needs **to be** reviewed" is correct.

"This needs reviewed" is not correct, there is no verb linking "needs" and "reviewed" together.

However, you could say "this needs review", where you use "review" as a noun instead of a verb. This would be equivalent to saying, "this tea needs sugar."